# Issue with Reselect. How to know what certain parameter in selector was changed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, reselect

**Reselect** allows us to memoize some data and update them if selector was changed. 
I have 2 arguments and, in depends on what argument, was changed return definite result.

```js
let instanse = ([state => state.selector1, state => state.selector2],(p1,p2)=>{
//if p1 was changed return result1
//if p2 was changed return result2
})
```

Can I implement it?